# Как экспортировать данные из базы в excel?

Tags: laravel, excel

На странице отображаются данные в тегах table полученные из базы. Как с помощью PhpSpreadsheet экспортировать полученные данные в Excel и скачать. В документации не совсем понятно объясняется. На данный момент используется Laravel.

```
public function index()
{
    $users=DB::table('bf_busers')->limit(30)->get();
    return view('posts.index')->with('users',$users);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Использую [Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) Для экспорта, выглядит так примерно, создаешь класс с тем что нужно выгружать, описываешь если надо какие то правила для ячеек:

```
<?php

namespace  App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;

class OrderExport implements FromCollection, WithColumnFormatting,ShouldAutoSize
{

    use Exportable;

    private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {

        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return $this->data;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'E'   => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'F'   => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'L'   => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
        ];
    }
}
```

Затем где то в контроллере создаешь коллекцию со строками для выгрузки

```
public function export(Request $request) {
  $collection = Order::search($request)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
  $collection->prepend([
            'ID',
            'Статус',
            'Бренд',
            'Продукция',
            'Серийный номер',            
            'Имя менеджера',
            'Имя покупателя',
            'Телефон покупателя',
            'Дата продажи'
        ]);
  return (new OrderExport($collection))->download('order.xlsx');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,а не подскажете ещё более универсальный вариант без привяки к Laravel ?

Comment: @netrox а чем тебе не подходит [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681839/write-data-from-array-to-sheet-using-phpspreadsheet-library) вариант ?

Comment: Там он не описал,как решил проблему .

Comment: @netrox А там же нижу примеры привели разве они не пашут ?